# Error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "geography":

Tags: c#, sql, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2012

> System.ArgumentException: 24200: The specified input does not
>   represent a valid geography instance.  Use MakeValid to convert the
>   instance to a valid instance. Note that MakeValid may cause the points
>   of a spatial instance to shift slightly. System.ArgumentException:  at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography..ctor(GeoData g, Int32 srid) at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Types.SqlGeography.GeographyFromText(OpenGisType
>   type, SqlChars taggedText, Int32 srid).

So I used `MakeValid` as

```
SET @Poly =  GEOGRAPHY::STPolyFromText(@PolygonString, 4326).MakeValid()
```

But I'm still getting the same error. Am I using it wrongly?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? This is a product specific question.

Comment: Can you give an example value of `@PolygonString` that gives this error?

Comment: 'POLYGON((-90.263672 37.509726, -90.263672 37.509726, -90.263672 37.509726, -90.263672 37.509726, -90.263672 37.509726))'

Answer (score 0):

This error "24200" can also be thrown when the SQL compatibility level is less than the minimum for geospatial support. This will manifest when you upgrade your SQL server instance across version boundaries and forget to update the Compat level after the upgrades. OP was in 2017 which could put them at SQL Compat Level 140 (SQL 2017) which would be ok for geospatial functions. If you were at SQL Server 2008, 2012, or 2014, then you would need to change the level to your most recent installed version, e.g. 2019 (150).

You set the SQL Compat level in the database (not server) properties under "Database Properties::Options -> Compatibility level".